# Can't put an image inside a div properly

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm working with Angular and trying to bind an image to a div background.
The background need to be darker from the original image so text can be include later :

**The problem Is** - The image does not show properly inside the boundaries of the div; some parts of the image are missing.

```css
.PictureCover {
  background-size: cover;
    margin: 10px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="PictureCover" style="background-image: 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
    ),
    url(http://a57.foxnews.com/global.fncstatic.com/static/managed/img/Entertainment/0/0/tom-cruise-playboy-interview-660.jpg);"></div>
```

**The url to the image from the example is temporary and will be replaced with a binding to a image from object in angular** so inculding 'background-image' inside the PictureCover css class is not an option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .PictureCover, you could add:
    background-position: center center;

```css
.PictureCover {
  background-size: cover;
    margin: 10px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
background-position: center center;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="PictureCover" style="background-image: 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
    ),
    url(http://a57.foxnews.com/global.fncstatic.com/static/managed/img/Entertainment/0/0/tom-cruise-playboy-interview-660.jpg);"></div>
```

Comment: I would like to get a result like the <img> does, he doesn't cut the image like your answer, but this is a really good answer so thanks very much, I will use it,

Comment: Do you mean you want to resize the div according to the size of the loaded image? The other thought I had was to change the background-size property from 'cover' to 'contain', but it won't fill your div.

Comment: I want to resize the image according to the size of the div. but dont delete this answer pls, just update it or add new one,